Getting cookie errors when embedding YouTube videos even when using nocookie source link
When embedding YouTube videos on my website I'm getting "Uses third party cookies" error even when using nocookie source link.
This seems similar to https://github.com/privacysandbox/privacy-sandbox-dev-support/issues/343
